# How to choose a file in install4j

Tags: install4j

During the installation process user have to choose a file from the local computer. That is a key to the 3rd party library we use, but should be registered on the user.

What is a proper Screen for doing that? 
I found `Folder selection` screen, but no way to select a file with this screen.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-defined screens in install4j are just form screens with a default configuration of form components.

To develop a screen with a file selector, add an empty form and then add a "File chooser" form component to it.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need.